# SQLite database when using BackgroundWorker c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have the following code to open a SQLite database. Everything works awesome when I'm trying to open it without a Background Worker. The problem is, that it loads big ammounts of data, so I want to throw it into the background.

```
_worker = new BackgroundWorker();
_worker.DoWork += ((s, x) =>
{
     _citiesList = new ObservableCollection<City>();
     _citiesList = (Application.Current as App).db.SelectCityCollectionCollection(selectString);
});
_worker.RunWorkerCompleted += ((s, x) =>
{
    LocationClearText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    SearchCityPromptList.ItemsSource = _citiesList.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.cityName.StartsWith(CitySearchBox.Text) || p.flatCityName.StartsWith(CitySearchBox.Text)).Take(30);
});
_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The error that is thrown is "Could not open database file: myDatabase.sqlite".

Like I said, everything works until I try to open it in BackgroundWorker. How should I change my code to make this work?

Comment: Where are you storing `_citiesList`? You should be using the Result of the `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: _citiesList is just a List<City>

Comment: Yes, but the point of the `BackgroundWorker` is so that you don't need to share a static variable. return your `List<>` from the `DoWork` method and access it inside the `RunWorkerCompleted` using `s.Result` - at the moment, there is potential for your SQL call to enumerate within your completed method

Comment: Still the same error when passing it as a Result.

Comment: Do you open a connection on the main thread then open another in the background worker?

Comment: Each time im doing something, Im closing the connection. So there arent 2 connections at the same time ever.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but it happens to be the first hit on google.

The best thing to do in this case is to..

```
lock(connection)
{
  connection.open();
  DoStuff(connection);
}
```

Lock will ensure that you're the only one utilizing the variable.  You, as in, the specific method.  Until it completes all others request to the variable will wait until the lock has cleared.

Here is a great read on how locks work and should be utilized in threading situations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx